# Alarm to the same active activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I've set an alarm to start an activity, say A.

If the intended A activity is not in the foreground, A will wake up and hit onResume(), where I check to see the source of it.

But what if A is IN the foreground, what happens to my intent ?

Thanks !

Comment: You should try it out and tell us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend how the [launchmode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) is defined for activity A. For instance, if it's set to standard:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity" android:launchMode="Standard">
```

it will spawn a second activity when the intent is fired, and spawn as many activities as there are intents, where's if it's set to "singleTop":

```
<activity android:name=".Activity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

it will simply route the intent to the instance of the activity that's already running. There are two more types: "singleInstance" and "singleTask", so see the documentation for more details in order to customize as you wish.

Comment: If singleTop is set (which is probably what you want to do), then the intent will be delivered to onNewIntent().